# How to pause MediaElement when single tap/touch on the screen - UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, mediaelement

I have to play a video using MediaElement. I want to pause the video when the user taps the screen. I found that there is double tapped event on MediaElement, but couldn't find any single touch event. How can I do this?

```xaml
<MediaElement Name="videoMediaElement" AreTransportControlsEnabled="True" Stretch="Fill" 
  MediaOpened="videoMediaElement_MediaOpened" CurrentStateChanged="Media_State_Changed">
    <MediaElement.TransportControls>
        <MediaTransportControls Background="Red" Foreground="White" 
          IsStopButtonVisible="True" IsStopEnabled="True" IsTextScaleFactorEnabled="True" 
          IsPlaybackRateEnabled="True" IsPlaybackRateButtonVisible="True" 
          IsFastForwardButtonVisible="True" IsFastForwardEnabled="True" 
          IsFastRewindButtonVisible="True" IsFastRewindEnabled="True"/>
    </MediaElement.TransportControls>
</MediaElement>
```

```cs
private async void Media_State_Changed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
{
    if (videoMediaElement.CurrentState == MediaElementState.Paused)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of events you can use for that, e.g. the `MouseLeftButtonDown` or `TouchDown` events. It's as simple as that:

```
private void element_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    ((MediaElement)sender).Pause();
}

private void element_TouchDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.TouchEventArgs e)
{
    ((MediaElement)sender).Pause();
}
```

---

By @JetChopper:

```
private void element_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ((MediaElement)sender).Pause();
}
```

Comment: I want the touch event only on above the video.Is it possible with these events?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *"on above"*, but I suggest you just give it a try.

Comment: Just use PointerPressed event. It works for any input device.

Comment: @JetChopper You want to add that as a separate answer or should I edit it into mine?